# Oracle XMLtype query

Tags: xml, oracle

I'm working my way up the Oracle XML learning curve.
I have an XML doc that main contain an 'Error/Text' element at any level.  I'd like to query the doc and get the text of each error message as its own record.  In my attempts so far, the text gets concatenated together into one record.
How can I get them in their own records?
Thank you.

```
with xmldoc_ as (
SELECT xmltype('
<B>
<A>
<Error><Text>Error #1</Text></Error>
</A>
<C>
<D>
<Error><Text>Error #2</Text></Error>
</D>
</C>
</B>
') object_value from dual)
select
XMLcast(
   XMLquery('//Error/Text' passing object_value returning content) 
   as varchar2(200)
) message
from xmldoc_
```

Comment: Sorry couldn't understand your question,can you show us the current and expected result

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought if you put changed the XPath expressions to

```
//Error[1]/Text
```

It would do what you want, but it doesn't.  The following slightly adjusted code will give you what you want. If you want to start doing a lot of XMLTYPE related stuff, it would be a good idea to read the XML developers guide, as Oracle can do a lot of stuff with XML.

```
with XML as
    (select xmltype(
    '<B>
<A>
<Error><Text>Error #1</Text></Error>
</A>
<C>
<D>
<Error><Text>Error #2</Text></Error>
</D>
</C>
</B>') as OBJECT_VALUE from dual
   )
   select column_value
     from XML,
          XMLTABLE
          (
             '//Error/Text/text()'
             passing OBJECT_VALUE
      )
/
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions253.htm):

```
SQL> with xmldoc_ as
  2  ( SELECT xmltype
  3           ( '<B>
  4               <A>
  5                <Error>
  6                 <Text>Error #1</Text>
  7                </Error>
  8               </A>
  9               <C>
 10                <D>
 11                 <Error>
 12                  <Text>Error #2</Text>
 13                 </Error>
 14                </D>
 15               </C>
 16              </B>'
 17           ) object_value
 18      from dual
 19  )
 20  select text
 21    from xmldoc_
 22       , xmltable
 23         ( '//Error'
 24           passing object_value
 25           columns text varchar2(20) path 'Text'
 26         )
 27  /

TEXT
--------------------
Error #1
Error #2

2 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.